# how to store values in one session in a certain condition

Tags: php, post, session-variables

**I want to store data from the $_POST to $_SESSION  which fits on certain condition when ever user clicks submit button. and i need to send that certified $_Session array to another page. However, my code is not working right. Could somebody help me on this? :(
**

'''

```
session_start();
$errorFound = 0;

function test_input($data)
{
  $data = trim($data); 
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialChars($data);
  return $data;
}

$cleanData_CUST_name = $_POST['cust']['cust[name]'];


if (isset($_POST['submit_booking'])){
    if (empty($_POST["cust[name]"])) {
        $nameErr = "Name is required";
        $errorFound++;
      } else {
            $name = test_input($_POST["cust[name]"]);
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $name)){
                $nameErr = "Only letters and whitespace are allowed.";
                $errorFound++;
       }if($errorFound ==0){
        $_SESSION['CUST'] =  $_POST['cust[name]']; 
       }
}
```

'''

Comment: is your `$_POST` is a multi dimensional array as this: `$cleanData_CUST_name = $_POST['cust']['cust[name]'];`

Comment: oh so if not, $cleanData_CUST_name = $_POST['cust[name]'];  this is gonna be correct?

Comment: you're checking if `if (empty($_POST["cust[name]"])) {` empty

Comment: yeah if  $_POST["cust[name]"] (which is user input name), it will display error. but my session array is still empty :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_booking'])){
if (empty($_POST["cust[name]"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
    $errorFound++;
  } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["cust[name]"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $name)){
            $nameErr = "Only letters and whitespace are allowed.";
            $errorFound++;
   }if($errorFound ==0){
    $_SESSION['CUST'] =  $_POST['cust[name]']; 
   }
}
}
```

you're missing to close a semicolon for `if (isset($_POST['submit_booking'])){`